# ASIO : get the port number of client

Tags: boost, boost-asio

In my application, a client connects to the server at a given port and host.

Now, I want to know the port number that is opened at the client's end.

How can I get this information ?

Also, at the server end, can I also get the port number at which the client is connecting to ?

Basicaly, I want to send some extra information to the server when the client connects.. So, I will dump a file when a client is created with the file name as the port number of the client and at the server end, I will again try reading a file whose name is the port number of the client...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now, I want to know the port number that is opened at the client's end.
>   Also, at the server end, can I also get the port number at which the client is connecting to ?

These questions seem to be the same to me. Unless you mean the port of the server, which you have to specify on both ends (and therefore already know).

Yes, you can get in your server the port of the connecting client along with the IP-address.

```
//boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket _socket;
_remoteAddress = _socket.remote_endpoint().address(); //You may call to_string() on it
_remotePort = _socket.remote_endpoint().port();
```